# Setting up a goal in Google Analytics that contains unique urls?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to setup a goal in Google Analytics where I want to see the dropoffs when someone goes through the order process.

My understanding is that I set a destination url (which is the thank you page) but need to add a funnel.

The last two steps are always the same:

1. www.domain.com/wishlist
2. www.domain.com/wishlist/confirmation

So I've set the destination to point 2 above.

**We have a fairly big catalogue with different categories and products. How can I enter a funnel without having to put in 100's of unique url's?**

The user can click through the following steps or go directly to any step below via a Google search, site search or promo banner.

1. /products (an overview of all the categories)
2. /product-categories (an overview of all the sub-categories)
3. /product-categories/aaa/bbb (an overview of the products within the sub categories)
4. /products/ccc (a product)

**"aaa", "bbb", "ccc" represent unique urls. How can I replace those but not put in unique url's?**

[image]

Comment: Use "regular expression" instead of "equal to" in the destination settings (because this also applies to the goal urls) and then use regex in your funnel urls. However I'm not sure if the use of regex would qualify this as a code question, and as a reporting question it is probably off-topic.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Would that make the url - /product-categories/.*/.* for step 3 of the funnel? (Not really sure where else to put this question, also seems plenty on the subject)

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Usually those questions are referred to webmasters.stackexchange.com. And I agree that the separation between coding/reporting questions for GA sometimes seem arbitrary. I still try to comply with this sites' rules, though.